# python interpreter incompatible with packages versions in requirements.txt

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `requirements.txt` file but my python version is not compatible with those versions required, what is the smartest way to upgrade the versions of the packages without changing too much of the original setup?

**I am following a book that has those reqs and I'm afraid of new versions may lead to unexpected code behavior or incompatibilities.**

I have already upgraded pip.
I don't want to up/downgrade python itself.

requirements.txt not compatible with `python 3.10`:

```
numpy==1.21.2
scipy==1.7.0
matplotlib==3.4.3
sklearn==1.0
pandas==1.3.2
```

Errors:

```
# pip install numpy==1.21.2              
Collecting numpy==1.21.2
  Downloading numpy-1.21.2.zip (10.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.3/10.3 MB 10.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [198 lines of output]
      setup.py:63: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.21.2 may not yet support Python 3.10.
```

Comment: If you're unwilling to downgrade python to an older version, that you're going to have to install newer packages and do testing. I would suggest that you use a tool like conda to maintain separate python instances. In that case you can maintain separate python versions on the same machine

Comment: Related docs: [Python Packaging Guide - Version specifiers](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/version-specifiers/#id4). There's a good chance that replacing the "matching clause" `==` with a "compatible clause" `~=` would do the trick. Many (most?) packages practice [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) or similarly inspired versioning schemes, where changes in the minor version number are backwards compatible.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to create a virtual environment with a compatible version of python.

Comment: In addition to @Brian61354270 comment, I checked packages in your list, they are only 4 minor versions behind current release, so there shouldn't be any incompatibility

Comment: Great advices from all, thanks.  Followed @Brian61354270 and it installed almost OK, had to bump mathplotlib to 3.5.1 to get rid of a package building problem (VS Build Tools 14) on Windows.